# KOMA-Script article, header 'Page x of y': total pages not displayed

Tags: page-numbering, lastpage

My 3 pages long article having the following code in the preamble produces *"Page x of **??**"* in the header, rather than *"Page x of **3**"* (where *x* stands for current page number).

What am I missing?

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{lastpage}}
```

Comment: Did you run the compiler for three times? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I was looking at the pdf preview; just compiled it 3 times with no difference in the output. Still ?? for last page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, *starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the number of the "last page" is not computed by `LaTeX`. If you look at the `log`-file, you should see something like:

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastpage' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

It means that `LaTeX` doesn't know what `lastpage` is (i.e. this `label` have not been defined previously).

If you look at the [documentation of the `lastpage` package](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage/lastpage.pdf), it is said that the `label` defined on the last page is `LastPage` (with `L` and `P` as capital letters).

Thus, **you should write `\pageref{LastPage}` instead of `\pageref{lastpage}`.** (Indeed, caps does matter in LaTeX.)

Comment: Thank you. The typo has been corrected and the issue resolved.